# Imported .fbx model is falling down when used as prefab in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3dsmax

[image: Inspector of the falling object]

I have made a model in the 3ds max and exported as .fbx file. Same model I have imported in Unity 3D and use it as Prefab. Model created in Unity 'eg:- GameObject -> Create Object -> Cube' is not falling down in(-y axis).

But the imported .fbx object as Prefab falls down as game is started (like object with physics component).

I have NOT added RigidBody to the object.

I want my imported object should behave like one created in Unity3d.

Do anyone know how I should prevent prefabs with imported objects to stuck at one place.(do not fall in - Y axis)

Thanks

Comment: Does every imported model fall or is it just this one? You could try some models from Asset Store for example.

Comment: NO, imported from Asset Store is working fine and check the properties of both the models (imported from 3ds Max and Downloaded from Asset Store) have same components

Comment: You could try to remove Animator-component (or if you don't have/want animations you can remove them from import settings as well)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1**

You have 'Apply Root Motion' set to true. If your animation moves the root bone then it's possible that what you are seeing is not actually falling but the character's root bone being moved to initial position.

Uncheck this and also see if your model still falls through the floor. If it doesn't then you need to adjust your animations accordingly.

If you are relying on animations to move your character about the scene rather than a character controller then you should look at the docs on Animator an see if there is a combination of settings that will work with your setup.

**ORIGINAL**

Have you added a character controller to it? That has a rigid body and colliders. So once you run the game it will get affected by gravity and fall down.

Comment: I have not added character controller to the imported model (I have created ROAD model). Still its falling down and I don't want this to happen. Components of the imported model are Animator. I am also generating that Object again and again with the help of script(prefab)

Comment: Can you try this. Run the game in editor. Press pause. Look at hierarchy window and select the object that is falling down. Screenshot the inspector and post it here.

Comment: I have added screenshot in the question